# Custom Dialog for Force Closed Android

Tags: android

I want my Application to show Custom Dialog When an Uncatch Exception occur.

For that reason, I am implementing Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.

I am successfully able to handle all my uncatch Exceptions.

And Try to show the Toast.

But My Toast is not Displayed because my Main Looper (i.e My Main Thread) is being stopped and My Whole Application get blocked.

I tried to create a Alternate Main Looper when Main Looper is being stopped. But for some reason my Alternate Main Looper does not get Any Message in MessageQueue.

Is there any other way to do that.

What I need is to Show the Error to User and Close the Erroneous Activity, Not my Whole Application.

Or Else is there any way that I can Handle all the uncatch Exception in an Activity.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think if the error reached this point your application would be kill (thus no context to display your dialog) - I'm not certain on that however.

You could try catching the error yourself, then displaying your dialog and then throwing the UncaughtExceptionHandler exception on the dialog's closing.

Comment: I have added the UncatchExceptionHandler at Application Class so I always has a Context available to show Dialog. But the Dialog will not be displayed because no Looper exist to show Dialog.